# ImportError: cannot import name 'tksupport'

Tags: python, tkinter, twisted, twisted.internet

I guess this is a dumb question, but I don't know how to solve my problem. I googled about it and also searched SO with no results.

I'm learning tkinter and twisted, and was going through a basic example, but cannot import tksupport.

I'm running ubuntu mate 16.04 (32bits), and python3.5.

I installed twisted using apt-get install python3-twisted, then when it didn't work I installed once more using pip3 install twisted.

Both this commands seemed to work just fine, and one of my imports (reactor) is working. This is my import

```
from twisted.internet import tksupport, reactor
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: In looking around the googles, I found a couple of instances of people claiming that tksupport hasn't been ported to Python3 yet, but wasn't able to find any confirmation

Comment: @BryanOakley the exact error message is the title of this post. Thanks

Comment: It appears `tksupport` is not in Python3's version of `twisted.internet` -- I confirmed `tksupport.py` exists in the Python2 version, but not the Python 3 version. Among other differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all modules in twisted have been ported to Python 3. `tksupport` has not been ported.

> Only some parts of Twisted have been ported, and therefore only a subset of modules are installed under Python 3. You can see the full list of ported modules in [twisted.python.dist3](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.4.1/api/twisted.python.dist3.html).

[Twisted Python3 documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/python3.html)

[List of twisted modules currently in Python3](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/twisted-16.4.1/twisted/python/dist3.py)